# voting issue - storing votes as serialize instead of multi rows

Tags: mysql

my question is : what is the best way
storing the vote of the user include the ip and answer id in new mysql row or making just ine field in the answer row include all votes as "serialize" data
and if
what is the type of files to store this serialized data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is almost always a bad idea to store multiple values in one column, as it becomes difficult to parse out the values you need and can make a column index unusable following the string operations necessary to extract a part.

Make a normalized table which stores one row per answer, per user.  If an individual answer is itself a single data point, it belongs as its own row.

If you are tracking users by IP:

```
CREATE TABLE votes (
  voteid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  userip VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  answerid INT NOT NULL
);
```

Plus, this gives you the benefit of being able to query your data in ways like:

```
/* Get vote count per user */
SELECT userip, COUNT(*) FROM votes GROUP BY userip;

/* Get users who have voted 3 or more times */
SELECT userip FROM votes GROUP BY userip HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

To accomplish the same thing with a serialized column, you would need to query it into application code, parse out the delimiters, and then perform your analysis.  To implement the second (count >= 3) in application code requires re-implementing lots of the things the database is already very good at, like sorting, grouping, and counting.

Answer (score 0):

You should create each distinct item as its own column.

This makes it much less complex to access individual columns. The queries will be less complex for you to write, in addition to generally being more efficient for MySQL.

It also allows you to specify different type and length requirements for each column. For example, you might have one Integer column, and one Character column, each with different storage requirements and implications for the type.

I recommend storing the IP address as in Integer column, [using the `INET_ATON()` and `INET_NTOA()` functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html).